# Testing jQyery.get with mocha.js does not work, nor do other Deferred (RSVP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I'm trying to get some JavaScript tests running with mocha.js. Everything works pretty good so far, but I have a big problem testing anything around jQuery requests or other promises/defers.

My code was working perfectly fine in the browser, previously heavily using `$.Deferred` but with Mocha i could not get it to run.

I tried different ways of writing it and also switched to a "proper" Promise library as apparently jQuery is known to cause trouble for its implementation.

Proper RSVP.Promises work fine, `RSVP.Defer` still not, and I can't get anything to work involving jQuery (like making Requests).

I did find some suggestions that wrapping jQuery into proper Promises should do the job but could not find any way of actually doing so that does not fail.

Here is a test case to show the issue:

```
'use strict';

var RSVP = require('rsvp');
var    $ = require('jquery');

describe('promises', function() {

  it('works with RSVP.Promise', function(done) {
    new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve();
    }).then(function() {
      done();
    });
  });

  it('works with RSVP.Deferred promise', function(done) {
    RSVP.defer().done(function() {
      done();
    }).resolve();
  });

  it('works with $.Deferred', function(done) {
    $.Deferred().done(function() {
      done();
    }).resolve();
  });

  it('works with $.get (promise syntax)', function(done) {
    $.get('http://google.com', function() {
      done();
    });
  });

  it('works with $.get (defered syntax)', function(done) {
    $.get('http://google.com').done(function() {
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Running with:

`$ mocha --compilers jsx:babel/register`

Gives me the following output:

```
promises
    ✓ works with RSVP.Promise
    1) works with RSVP.Deferred promise
    2) works with $.Deferred
    3) works with $.get (promise syntax)
    4) works with $.get (defered syntax)


  1 passing (59ms)
  4 failing

  1) promises works with RSVP.Deferred promise:
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:17:26)

  2) promises works with $.Deferred:
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:23:21)

  3) promises works with $.get (promise syntax):
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:31:7)

  4) promises works with $.get (defered syntax):
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:37:7)
```

Other tests run perfectly fine as long as there is no jQuery Promise/Defer involved.

Is there a better solution than to drop jQuery for making requests or am I doing something generally wrong? The aim of the tests is to test the actual request/response, so mocking out the requests is also no option here.

Like i said the code runs perfectly fine in the browser with either way of using Promise/Defer jQuery or not. So I guess it's a issue with theTest runner or the node.js environment (?) it runs in.

Answer (score 1):

To test HTTP requests you can use: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

which is great, or instead of using jQuery to make HTTP requests you could use: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

I think it is a more standard way in nodeJS than using jQuery.

Comment: Indeed, you should always mock HTTP requests when testing. You aren't testing that you can _make a request_, but that a request handler _produces the expected result_.

Comment: If you want to do functional/integration testing you can even make requests, to see if the whole process works.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. I should have been more clear and said 'unit testing'.

Comment: You are right, in unit tests you should mock out the requests to only test the own behaviour. In my case i really do want to make the requests, since my test case is actually checking if my code works against the result of the request (as the result might change over time).

Comment: And the main target is for the code to run in the browser. I'm not sure if running tests should define how the browser code is written (using a library made for node instead of for the browser).
Superagent seems to work in browser too (but seems to lack support for older ones), so i might give it a try though.